# wsgi cant find modules in virtualenv in weblate + apache2 + wsgi setup

Tags: python-3.x, apache, virtualenv, wsgi, weblate

I got the weblate running in dev mode with :8000. But I am not able to get it running in apache2 with wsgi within the virtual environment, where everything worked.

Based on apache errors, it could not even find django installed.
I did that but saw another error of a missing module.
Its clear that wsgi is not respecting/searching for modules in the virtualenv for python.

My server is Ubuntu 19.04.

Please suggest.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName xxyyzz.com

    # DATA_DIR/static/favicon.ico
    Alias /favicon.ico xxyyzz/weblate-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/data/static/favicon.ico

    # DATA_DIR/static/
    Alias /static/ xxyyzz/weblate-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/data/static/
    <Directory xxyyzz/weblate-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/data/static/>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # DATA_DIR/media/
    Alias /media/ xxyyzz/weblate-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/data/media/
    <Directory /home/weblate/data/media/>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # Path to your Weblate virtualenv
    WSGIDaemonProcess weblate python-path=xxyyzz/weblate-env
    WSGIProcessGroup weblate
    WSGIApplicationGroup weblate

    WSGIScriptAlias / xxyyzz/weblate-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/weblate/wsgi.py process-group=weblate
    WSGIPassAuthorization On

    <Directory xxyyzz/weblate-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/weblate/>
        <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Same as: https://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/admin/install.html

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the example configuration is wrong, it should be using `python-path` instead of `python-home` for `WSGIDaemonProcess`. I've just [fixed this in Weblate](https://github.com/WeblateOrg/weblate/commit/79f26954d6033600e9f52eb749ed2799211e23f0) and you will probably need such change in your configuration as well.